# JTextArea does not support Font Khmer

Tags: java, fonts

I have created a JTextArea for inputting comment in Khmer Language but when I write Khmer Font, it does not show correctly in JTextArea. Also, when I try to use function getText() from JTextArea. It show text as "???? ???? ???".
Could you help me please? Thanks you.

```js
        tadd = new JTextArea("តេស្ត"); 
        tadd.setFont(new Font("Khmer​ Os", Font.PLAIN,15)); 
        tadd.setSize(200, 75); 
        tadd.setLocation(200, 300); 
        tadd.setLineWrap(true);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the setLocale() method?

Comment: @Palo, I have already tired but it does not work.